# StencilJS: Can @Watch be used on @State

Tags: stenciljs

Is the following code valid ?

```
      @State() state;
      @Watch('state')
      stateHandler(s) {
        ...
      }
```

From what I can read on the doc, it doesn't mention it. However, the `@Watch` does get triggered in my example, so I does assume it does work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is valid. When a component's Prop or State property changes, the @Watch decorator will fire the method it's attached to. It is true that this is not well specified in the documentation.